# d($y(n),y(n+1)$)$<=1/n$ then is {$y(n)$} a Cauchy Sequence? d($y(n),y(n+1)$)$<=1/n^2$, then is {$y(n)$} Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let {$y(n)$} be a sequence in a complete metric space (X,d) such that d($y(n),y(n+1)$)$<=1/n$. Give any example of such a sequence {$y(n)$} which is not Cauchy. If we take d($y(n),y(n+1)$)$<=1/n^2$, then is {$y(n)$} Cauchy?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1 / n = \infty$.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$ is finite. Use the triangle inequality to bound $d(y_n, y_m)$.

Comment: Follow the hints to prove the first is not necessarily Cauchy (i.e. you can't prove it is from $d(y(n), y(n+1)) \le /n$. while the second is.